Elliptic curve from a spectrahedron, why is semipositiveness equivalent to the following conditions?
$$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; A(x,y) := \begin{bmatrix}
x+1 & 0 & y\\
0 & 2 & -x-1 \\
y & -x-1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \succeq
 0$$
In the book from Blekherman (2012) ex 2.7:

To obtain scalar inequalities defining the set, let $p_A(t) = det(tI - A(x,y)) = t^3 + p_2 t + p_1 t + p_0$ be the characteristic polynomial of A(x,y). Positive semidefiniteness of A(x,y) is then equivalent to the conditions.

$$-p_2 = x + 5 \geq 0$$
$$p_1 = -x^2 + 2x - y^2 + 7 \geq 0$$
$$-p0 = 3 + x - x^3 - 3x^2 - 2y^2 \geq 0$$
How are these inequalities obtained? I suspect it has to do with principle minors, but I don't see it.

The  $$\det(tI - A(x,y)) = t^3-t^2 (x+5)-t \left(x^2-2 x+y^2-7\right)+x^3+3 x^2-x+2 y^2-3$$
Now, just align each $p_i$ with the factors.
